# Add prefix for target_include_directories

Tags: c++, cmake

I have following project structure for stm32 library:

```
-lib
  -include
    -f0
    -f1
    -f4
CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt contains `add_library` command for each MCU family and `target_include_directories` for each library. `target_include_directories` adds f0/f1/f4 folder, so user can include headers by `#include <timer.h`, for example. But it's not good, because headers names can conflict with other project deps.

I can link whole `include` folder and add global `timer.h` and other with `#ifdef F0 #include "f0/timer.h"`, but in this case user can see other families folder (for example, he uses F0, but see f1 and f4 folders).

My question: can I write `target_include_directories` and add fake prefix for files from directory? I want to include `f0` folder but force user write `#include <lib/timer.h>`?

I think about reorganize my library, but it's seems so ugly.

Comment: any include "prefix" must be reflected by respective directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I write target_include_directories and add fake prefix for files from directory?

No. The directories `<anything>` is mapped 1:1 to directory structure. If you want to add a prefix, you have to *copy* files into a directory. You can copy them in CMake and add that copied directory to include path if you want, but note it makes working on the project confusing.

Consider refactoring your project and putting platform specific includes in separate directories. Typically:

```
lib/
├── f0
│   └── include
│       └── lib
├── f1
│   └── include
│       └── lib
└── f4
    └── include
        └── lib
```